# How do you get a flex grid to scale with page size instead of wrapping using css

Tags: html, css

5.30.20 EDIT: Works on stackoverflows code snippet viewer but not on chrome or any html hosting. Here's the hosted file:

https://unholytool.htmlpasta.com/

wondering what's going on.

---

Here's an image to show what I'm talking about

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggQcF.png

So I'm new to CSS and I'm not finding a lot of luck on google.

I have a media query set up that works great for mobile, however I can't seem to get it to display correctly on different monitor sizes.

On very wide screens it works well and displays four columns and the left sidebar.

However as the screen shrinks it displays a wonky view of three images on one row and one image on the next row

This is my current display with the answer below

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 18px;
}

.body {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px height:90px max-width: 30%;
}

.hero {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.leftsidebar {
  display: none;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .column {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
 

.container {
  display: grid;
}

.leftsidebar {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: inherit;
}

.products {
  grid-column: 2;
}


}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Our Catalog</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div>
    <img class="logo" src="logoimg.jpeg">

  </div>
  <hr class="divider">
  <div>
    <picture>
      <source media="(max-width: 799px)" class="hero" srcset="heroimg1.jpeg, heroimg2.jpeg">
      <img class="hero" src="heroimg1.jpeg">
    </picture>
  </div>


  <hr class="divider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="leftsidebar">
      <img src="img.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <div class="products">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1>product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="img.jpeg" />
          <h1> product</h1>
          <p>$100</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divider">
  <br>
  <h3>Return Policy | Shipping Policy | Privacy Policy | About Us | Our Cause</h3>
  <br>
  <hr class="divider">


</body>

</html>
```

I've tried a lot of stuff, including using both flex-shrink and flex-grow properties on all elements,

messing with height and width attributes setting them between auto and a %.

and setting a % with the flex property

Any ideas? I'm trying to keep javascript to a minimum so CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured your flexbox CSS and it should work as per your requirement. I have also added `</div>` for every `<div class="column">`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="image.jpeg" />
    <h1> text</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="image.jpeg" />
    <h1> text</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="image.jpeg" />
    <h1>text</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="image.jpeg" />
    <h1>text</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's wierd, its not working for some reason. Let me post the rest of my code.

Comment: have you run the code snippets I posted and is it working as expected?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I posted the whole page code above

Comment: you have changed the code in `@media screen and (min-width: 1050px)` which means it only runs for screen size above 1050px. Try to change in the default CSS. Also, you could post your codes into the stack snippets by stack overflow. So that we can run the code snippets above to see the results. My code snippet works, right?

Comment: Thats the goal, to get it to run for screen sizes above that width. The mobile view is working well.

Comment: I've posted the codes into the snippets and they work there. However when I open the html file in chrome  its not working at all.

Comment: Do you have the HTML file hosting somewhere live so that I could look at it? If not, you may try to upload in [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) if you want.

Comment: I check your [unholytool.htmlpasta.com] and can reproduce the issue on chrome. You are almost there already. Can you please change the min-width from 1100px to lower like 1080px (or maybe lower)? I have tested and it should work as aspected.

Comment: Worked - Thank you!